# Serilog dotnet core function app and sql sink

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I need to use dotnet5 with Azure Functions so followed the guidance to create a new solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide.

This worked great so next job was to add in serilog with sinks for console and sql server.

I have added nuget packages:

- Serilog.AspNetCore v4.1.0
- Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer v5.6.0

Here is the Program.Main:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string EventName = "Main";
    var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
    {
        AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
        {
            new SqlColumn
                {ColumnName = "EventName", DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, DataLength = 32, NonClusteredIndex = true}
        }
    };

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Azure", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                    logEventFormatter: new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(),
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug,
                    connectionString: "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SmsRouter",
                    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                    {
                        TableName = "LogEvents",
                        AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                    },
                    columnOptions: columnOptions)
                .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting up {EventName}", EventName);
        var host = new HostBuilder()
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(s =>
        {
            //services configured here
        })
        .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

You can see the line *Log.Information("Starting up {EventName}", EventName);* This works and is logged to both console and Sql Server :)

After the App is started it will sit and wait for a Http request - as shown below:

```cs
[Function("SendSimpleSms")]
public async Task<QueueAndHttpOutputType> RunSimple([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    string EventName = "SendSimpleSms";
    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting: {EventName}", EventName);
```

My problem is, this log request "Starting: SendSimpleSms" is logged to the console window but not to Sql Server.

Anyone see what I have wrong please?

Comment: Enable Serilog's self-logging to see what's wrong with eg `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg));` or `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));`

Comment: BTW there's no `LocalDB` in Azure, so I assume the code you posted is only for testing? In production you'd have to use a connection string pointing to a real database, either Azure SQL or SQL Server on a VM. BUT both may end up being more expensive per MB than Log Analytics or App Insights

Comment: Yes localdb for testing. I was using application insights but I find the 5 minute delay frustrating. Also, mixing up my custom log entries with those from the Az Func host doesn't feel right.

Comment: The SQL Server sink *also* buffers log messages. Logging and monitoring are different beasts, with different requirements. Logging has large messages and latency, monitoring the opposite. If you want low latency you should use a Prometheus sink or OpenTelemetry, which was built *precisely for cloud environments*. [ASP.NET Core fully supports OpenTelemetry now](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/opentelemetry-net-reaches-v1-0/), emitting Activity/Span IDs that allow you to track all calls made for a specific request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos for making me aware of the Serilog self-logging.

I added the following into program.main, after the LoggerConfiguration:

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
```

This then made me aware that the sql sink was unable to log because the length of a custom property exceeded that of its column